# Pen Pressure Sensitivity on Huion

Tags: drivers, graphics, tablet

Okay, so, I'm pretty newb to Ubuntu. I know about using the terminal and that's about it.
So when I went looking for the drivers for Huion, I expected a simple

```
sudo apt-get *insert driver here*
```

I didn't find that, I found hard to understand lingo and a really beginner-unfriendly installation.

Can someone provide me with step-to-step, easy to follow instructions on installing the driver? I just need it for Paint Tool Sai to work with pressure sensitivity.